# How can i check, is SoapClient use cached wsdl or not?

Tags: php, caching, soap, https

I use [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php). And i get message from API provider that my source requests wsdl at each request. But i see that after executing in /tmp appear file with wsdl data, i suppose this is cache.

How can i check, is cache really used or not? API use https so i can't use something like tcpflow to check that.

Of course i can use some pure php soap implementation and use debugger, but at this point i don't want do that.

Cache should be used. APIs admin said that i don't use cache and create too much load. But i can't check on my side is this true or not. And my question - how can i check that?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass this option to your SoapClient, you can be sure that cache is not being used.

```
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
```

Or, if you WANT cache, you can use either of these options:

```
WSDL_CACHE_DISK
WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
WSDL_CACHE_BOTH
```

Comment: But cache should be used. APIs admin said that i don't use cache and create too much load. But i can't check on my side is this true or not.

Comment: updated, try adding one of these options to make sure you are using cache

Answer (score 0):

To check if your cache is really used, you should monitor your network traffic.
You have multiple options to do this, the one I preferred is using an HTTP(s) proxy who logs all traffic.

You should already see your request in `tcpflow` (but not its content), when cache is disabled.